# I need to mask or suppress if null in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Looking for Crystal Reports help!  Crystal Reports 2013 SP5 V14.1.5.1501 Windows 7 pro environment.

I have table.date_field that is a date field formatted as such:  xx/xx/xxxx.  I'm putting it in a report that will be exported as a .csv so the field has to be 10 spaces which works fine if there is a date in table.date_field.

If table.date_field is null it returns ;; (.rpt has to be separated by semicolons).

I tried creating 2 formulas one I called @date_field_format and one I called @date_field_tweak.

@date_field_format has the following formula:

```
picture({table.date_field},'xx/xx/xxxx')
```

@date_field_tweak has the following formula:

```
if isnull ({@date_field_format}) then
    space(10)
else
    left(trim(totext({@date_field_format}))+space(10),10)
```

Using @date_field_tweak on the .rpt returns: `;2//21//201;`

Any suggestions on how to get table.date_field on a report formatted like this xx/xx/xxxx with 10 spaces inserted in place of the date if table.date.field isnull?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

assuming your date format from database is `29/04/2015`

```
if isnull ({Sheet1_.date}) then
    space(10)
else

Split(ToText(Cdate({Sheet1_.date})),"/")[1]+"/"+
Split(ToText(Cdate({Sheet1_.date})),"/")[2]+"/"+
Split(ToText(Cdate({Sheet1_.date})),"/")[3]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the closest I've gotten but it's still not the way I need it to be.  Everything looks good except the month which needs to be 2 digits xx/xx/xxxx.  Having said that; it's an oracle db so the dates are stored xx-month-xx (29-APR-15).  I wonder now if that is not a big part of my problem......

Comment: Now what is the issue my solution works for that aswell

Comment: @Meg The way you phrased your question suggests that the field in question is a varchar data type (which it really shouldn't be), but your comment here suggests it's a date. Which one is it?